# Show UIView programmatically when no posts gotten

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I want to show a UIView that has a label in it saying something like: "You have no posts", when `update.count == 0`. I tried to do that but the app crashes when I try.

What have I done wrong? Here is my code:

```
let noPostView: UIView = {
        let iv = UIView()
        iv.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        //iv.image = UIImage(named: "iphoneSample")
        //iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if updates.count == 0 {
            noPostView.anchorToTop(tableView.topAnchor, left: tableView.leftAnchor, bottom: tableView.bottomAnchor, right: tableView.rightAnchor)
            noPostView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100).active = true
            noPostView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100).active = true


            tableView.addSubview(noPostView)
        }
        return updates.count
    }
```

**Got this error amongst much more:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x61000067f280 "UIView:0x7fdbcbd21490.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x610000660a40 "UITableView:0x7fdbcd86a600.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Comment: what the crash report

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of commenting with such complex content. Thanks.

Comment: @EricAya I'm sorry. Edited question.

Comment: @D.Finna No problem. Thank you for editing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `tableView.addSubview(noPostView)` above your constraining.

Also you shouldn't need the `heightAnchor` and `widthAnchor` if you're constraining to all 4 sides right?

```
tableView.addSubview(noPostView)

noPostView.anchorToTop(tableView.topAnchor, left: tableView.leftAnchor, bottom: tableView.bottomAnchor, right: tableView.rightAnchor)
```

Comment: That did it! Do you know how I can center the UIView? :-)

Comment: Use `centerXAnchor` `centerYAnchor` instead http://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/

Comment: I did this: `noPostView.anchorToTop(tableView.centerYAnchor, left: tableView.centerXAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil)` but it centers the top left corner, not the middle of the UIView :)

Comment: Well yeah! In that code you're aligning `noPostView.topAnchor` to `tableView.centerYAnchor` :) did you check the use your loaf link?

Comment: `noPostView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true` I feel like you could have picked that one out there matey :)

Comment: I'm very new to setting constraints programmatically, so I had no clue :D Thank you so much!

Comment: OK no worries, give that blog post a read, it should put you on the right path.